# Change background image of a div from <input> without page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I have `<input type="file">` tag. I need to select an image and change the background of the image to the input image without refreshing or reloading the page. Is it possible ? If yes, how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but you'd have to make an AJAX file uploader - Javascript can't access the contents of a file input any any meaningful way.

Comment: Can I do it without involving server side ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery and do this:

```
$('#imgID').attr ('src', 'new path');
```

That will change the image without reloading the page.

Comment: I need to change it based on user input from <input> tag. There is no fixed new path.

Comment: Then you use a variable for the path. This is just the framework, you can make it work for you.

Comment: There is no path. I want <input> from client side. For example, I want an image (someimage.png) which is currently in my desktop to be the background of a div in HTML page.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.